# vb.net function branching based on optional parameters performance

Tags: vb.net

So I was coding a string search function and ended up with 4 since they needed to go forwards or backwards or be inclusive or exclusive. Then I needed even more functionality like ignoring certain specific things and blah blah.. I figured it would be easier to make a slightly bigger function with optional boolean parameters than to maintain the 8+ functions that would otherwise be required.

Since this is the main workhorse function though, performance is important so I devised a simple test to get a sense of how much I would lose from doing this. The code is as follows:

```
main window:
Private Sub testbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles testbutton.Click
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim ret As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 100000000

    Dim t As Integer = Environment.TickCount

    For i = 0 To count
        ret = superfunction(rand.Next, False)
    Next

    t = Environment.TickCount - t
    Dim t2 As Integer = Environment.TickCount

    For i = 0 To count
        ret = simplefunctionNeg(rand.Next)
    Next

    t2 = Environment.TickCount - t2
    MsgBox(t & " " & t2)
End Sub

The functions:

Public Module testoptionality
    Public Function superfunction(a As Integer, Optional b As Boolean = False) As Integer
        If b Then
            Return a
        Else
            Return -a
        End If
    End Function
    Public Function simpleFunctionPos(a As Integer)
        Return a
    End Function
    Public Function simplefunctionNeg(a As Integer)
        Return -a
    End Function

End Module
```

So pretty much as simple as it gets. The weird part is that the superfunction is consistently twice faster than either of the simple functions (my test results are "1076 2122"). This makes no sense.. I tried looking for what i might have done wrong but I cant see it. Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set a return type for simple function. So they return Object type.
So when you using `simpleFunctionNeg` function application convert `Integer` to `Object` type when returning value, and then back from `Object` to `Integer` when assigning returning value to your variable

After setting return value to `Integer` `simpleFunctionNeg` was little bid faster then `superfunction`

Comment: facepalm, of course! :D still, the results are encouraging enough to go down the optional route.